# Plot a 3D surface plot based on points from ginput using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ginput

I am trying to plot peaks (3D topographical peaks) on ginput() points specified by a user. These peaks have to be in the form of a 3D surface plot as shown in the example image on this link [3D surface plot peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULh46.png) .So far I have managed to acquire the points from the ginput() function and separated them into two different arrays one with x coordinates another with y coordinates. How do I go about plotting these peaks on these points using the cosine wave?

I am still new to python so I have written a few lines of pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve in order to try and add more clarity to my question.

```
import sys, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

pts = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

Npeaks = input(' Enter your number of peaks here..')
pts = plt.ginput(Npeaks)

x=map(lambda x: x[0],pts)  # creating an array with x coordinates
y=map(lambda x: x[1],pts)  # creating an array with y coordinates
```

Pseudo code of the code I am trying to achieve

```
if number_of_peaks > 0 :
    ax.plot_surface( plot a peak at those points )

else:
    sys.exit()


ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(value , value )
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim( value , value )
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim( value , value )

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a question about a specific mathematical function, but what your trying to do is unclear. In any case it is not a programing question until you specify your function in some way or another.

Comment: ok let me edit it thanks